# android How to asynchronous request data and synchronous display data

Tags: android

I have two listview in my activity. I use asynhttpclient request data two times, but I don't know how to monitor the two times request to refresh my listview.

There are some codes.

```
loadData( Constant.newGameUrl ,"new");
loadData( Constant.hotGameUrl ,"hot");


/**
 * request data
 * @param url 
 * @param type 
 */
public void loadData( String url, 
        final String type,final int initpage){

    H5RestClient.request(url, null, new OnRequestListener(){

        @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
        @Override
        public void onRequestFinish(boolean ret, String data) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            List<Game> games = new ArrayList<Game>();
            if( ret == true ){

                try {
                    games = JsonParseUtil.parseGame(data);
                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                if( games != null ){
                    netStateView.show(NetState.CONTENT);
                    if( type.equals("new")){

                        listNew.addAll(games);

                        newAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//this listview

                    }else if( type.equals("hot") ){
                        listHot.addAll(games);

                        hotAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//I want to display the two list view


                    }

                }
                else{

                    Toast.makeText(context, "result is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }


            }else{
                Toast.makeText(context, "request is failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

    });

}
```

public static void request(final String url, final RequestParams params, final OnRequestListener listener) {

```
    AsyncHttpResponseHandler handler = new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, String responseBody){

            Log.i(TAG, "success  "+responseBody);
            listener.onRequestFinish(true, responseBody);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable e, String responseBody){

            Log.e(TAG, "fail  "+responseBody);

            listener.onRequestFinish(false, responseBody + "");

        }
    };


    client.get(url, handler);
```

}

How to display the two listview at the same time?

newAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//this listview
hotAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//I want to display the two list view

Comment: AsyncHttpClient for Android has an `onSuccess`-method that returns your response once the request is completed. Regular `AsyncTask`s have an `onPostExecute`-method.

Comment: I know the onSuccess method. I want to display the two listview at the same time but the data returned at different time.

Comment: Then you will have to post some code and show us what you have already tried, what your specific problems are.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use Google Volley librairy for HTTP request.

See the doc here : http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Some code for your problem :

```
StringRequest strRequest1 = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
         // CODE REQUEST 1

    }
}, 0, 0, null, null);

StringRequest strRequest2 = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
         // CODE REQUEST 2

    }
}, 0, 0, null, null);

RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
rq.add(strRequest1);
rq.add(strRequest2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two booleans, one per transaction. Once a transaction is complete, it checks the two boolean. If the two are true, you display your data, if not it only sets its boolean to true...